# Is there a connection between different roots of n?

Tags: math, root, square-root

Let's say there is an integer n, e.g. 9, is there a connection (like a logical row of numbers e.g. 2, 4, 6, 8...) between:

```
√9  = 3; ∛9 = 2.08008; ∜9 = 1.732050808; ...
```

So is there any connection between **3**, **2.08008**, **1.732050808**, ...?
And if yes, which connection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, could you explain why do you call all of them *square* roots?

Comment: Ooops, hehe, @Cerberus.

Comment: Now fixed with an edit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there a way to transfer this question to the mathematica.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

The thing what you mentioned is totally not a square root. Every positive number have only one square root. 
Like √9=3, √25=5, √1=1, √15=3.872 and so on.

What you mentioned is its cube root, fourth root etc.
 So every number has only one root. Not multiple.

Comment: I know that. My actual question is if there is a connection between this roots like a logical row of numbers?

Comment: what do you mean to say by logical row of numbers?

Comment: E.g. 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12.... Guess the next number: 14.   Is there sth. like that for these 3 values: 3, 2.08008, 1.732050808...?

Comment: so basically you want to know the sequence of all the roots of a given number. is it?

Comment: Well, I guess it is.